# How to repeat a section of the program until the input is correct?

Tags: python, loops

I want my code to be repeated until the player guesses correctly.

```
ghuess=input("state a number between 1-100")
if ghuess>number:
    print "too high try again!"
elif ghuess<number:
    print "too low try again!"
else:
    print "well done! ghuess you have won.."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "3"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2"
    time.sleep(1)
    print "1"
    time.sleep(1)
    print prize
```

Comment: use a `while not isFound` before the `=input` and add `isFound=True` in the else part. and `isFound=False` before the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [`while`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Loops#While_loops)-loop there. This means you're looping the question again infinitely until you've reached a satisfactory result.

```
while True:
    ghuess=input("state a number between 1-100")
    if ghuess>number:
        print "too high try again!"
    elif ghuess<number:
        print "too low try again!"
    else:
        # Jackpot, exit the loop.
        break
print "well done! ghuess you have won.."
time.sleep(1)
print "3"
time.sleep(1)
print "2"
time.sleep(1)
print "1"
time.sleep(1)
print prize
```

Comment: but my number is already randomly chosen.number=random.randrange(100)

Comment: That was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally approached with a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    ... # do your thing
    if finished: # are we done here?
        break # leave
... # execution resumes here after break
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution without a `break`:

```
isFound = False
while not isFound:
    ghuess=input("state a number between 1-100")
    if ghuess>number:
        print "too high try again!"
    elif ghuess<number:
       print "too low try again!"
    else:
        isFound = True
        print "well done! ghuess you have won.."
        time.sleep(1)
        print "3"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "2"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "1"
        time.sleep(1)
        print prize
```